# Upload image in different folder for different user_id

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I have made a user registration form which includes user_id, name, password, email, and also uploaded images from the user. I would like these images to be stored for different users in different folders.

For example, if a user_id is "aa" then create a new folder name "aa" and the image is saved to the folder name "aa" and so on..

I searched on Google but could not found a better solution for my problem. If you know about this problem then please help me. Thanks.

Comment: create a folder for that user with user_id and upload the image to that folder. check this for more detail http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="main" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input name="image" type="file" />//file upload
</form>


<?php
if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $errors      = array();

    $allowed_ext = array(
        'png',
        'bmp',
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'JPG',
        'PNG',
        'JPEG'
    ); //do neccessary validation

    $file_name   = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $array       = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext    = end($array);
    $file_size   = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp    = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    if (!(in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) == false) || empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {

        if ($file_size < 40097152 || empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
            if (empty($errors)) {
                $dir    = "./images";
                $userid = isset($_POST['userid']) ? $_POST['userid'] : "";
                $dir1   = $dir . "/" . $userid;
                if (!is_dir($dir1)) {
                    mkdir($dir1);
                }

                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $dir1 . "/" . $file_name);

            } else {

                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    $flag = 0;
                    echo "<script language=javascript> alert(\"File upload error

    \");</script>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            $flag = 0;
            echo "<script language=javascript> alert(\"File Size Limit 20MB\");</script>";
        }
    } else {
        $flag = 0;
        echo "<script language=javascript> alert(\"Invalid Upload File Format\");</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sir thank you please explain me I implement this code its not working.may be i am making some mistake

Comment: thankyou sir but i want to upload 3 image in same user_id how can i do this ,please reply me sir

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$user_id = 'aa';
$upload_dir = "uploads/". $user_id;
//Check for folder if not exist create 
if (!file_exists($upload_dir)) {
      mkdir($upload_dir);
}

// Move the uploaded file
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $upload_dir.'/'. $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
```

You can use this link to go about uploading image http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 1):

i think you can try this to create directory

`mkdir(path,mode,recursive,context)`..

for more detail please check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_mkdir.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php), so

```
mkdir ($user_id);
```

Comment: Look into manual, I added link to that function. The rest of image upload, incl. `move_uploaded_files()` you have, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a directory named "images"

2- generate a user id and save it in the variable $id

3- If( ! isDir ($id) )
          mkdir($id) ;

4- move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["image"]["name"],  "images/$id/".$id.".png");

5- done...